# Help in solving differential equation: $x^2\ln^2(x)\cdot y''- 2x\ln(x)y'+(2+\ln(x)-2\ln^2(x))y=x^2\ln^3(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling with following differential equation. I tried using normal form but, it is getting very complicated.

$$x^2\ln^2(x)\cdot y''- 2x\ln(x)y'+(2+\ln(x)-2\ln^2(x))y=x^2\ln^3(x)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by substituting $y=\frac{v\cdot \ln{x}}{x}$ into the ODE. Evaluating derivatives:
$$y'=\frac{x\ln{x}\cdot v'+v-v\ln{x}}{x^2}$$
$$y''=\frac{x^2\ln{x}\cdot v''-2x(\ln{x}-1)\cdot v'+(2\ln{x}-3)\cdot v}{x^3}$$
Substituting into the ODE, and after some tedious simplification, you should obtain:
$$x\ln^3{x}\cdot v''-2\ln^3{x}\cdot v'=x^2\ln^3{x}$$
Dividing both sides by $x\ln^3{x}$ gives:
$$v''-\frac{2}{x}\cdot v'=x \tag{1}$$
Notice that we may now reduce $(1)$ to a first order linear ODE by substituting $w=v'$, giving:
$$w'-\frac{2w}{x}=x \tag{2}$$
This can easily be solved using the integrating factor method.